# No iPhone6 or iPhone6+ Simulators in XCode6

Tags: ios, xcode6

On a new project in Xcode 6 I don't have iPhone6 and iPhone 6+ simulators. Why is that?

I have simulators up to iPhone5s.

I have tried reinstalling Xcode but it doesn't fix it.

Anyone have any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Which app? share the link please.

Comment: @gran33, Xcode... And Shvalb, post pictures.

Comment: Any chance you are using one of earlier Beta'a?

Comment: Do you install xCode 6 from AppStore?

Comment: Ha ha, try to scroll menu with simulators list.

Comment: It's XCode6 official release from AppStore. In addition, I don't seem to have this folder: ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the iPhone 6 and Plus as a simulator: In xCode go to `Windows` -> `Devices` and press the `plus` in the bottom corner and add the devices that you wish.

Answer (score -1):

You use old version of Xcode. Go to AppStore and update to 6. May be you have Xcode 6, but you run your project in old version.

[image]